# Parsing JSON data to find one element

Tags: sql, json, parsing, sql-server-2016

I'm sifting through a JSON movie database and can get most of the data without a problem.  For each film, I've put the raw JSON in an nvarchar(max) column called jsondata, then added other columns to populate for indexing and quick retrieval purposes.

With my UPDATE statement, I'm able to populate all columns except for one, in which I need to parse through and find an element.

Here's an example of the JSON:

```
{
"title": "Amnesia Love",
"genres": [{
    "id": 35,
    "name": "Comedy"
}],
"id": 508989,   
"original_language": "tl",
"overview": "A guy is trying to discover his true identity after being found unconscious in a remote island.",
"popularity": 2.583,
"release_date": "2018-02-28",   
"credits": {
    "cast": [{
        "cast_id": 2,
        "character": "",
        "credit_id": "5a9af6ecc3a3680b7d024627",
        "gender": 0,
        "id": 1230955,
        "name": "Paolo Ballesteros",
        "order": 1,
        "profile_path": "/8Cey11JPMWBCGuIcKBXvb6OQ7Je.jpg"
    },
    {
        "cast_id": 3,
        "character": "",
        "credit_id": "5a9af6f3c3a3680b57024465",
        "gender": 0,
        "id": 1166094,
        "name": "Yam Concepcion",
        "order": 2,
        "profile_path": "/fiPaXTkq440VHXDqlMRHtOpoLWT.jpg"
    }],
    "crew": [{
        "credit_id": "5a9af6cc0e0a260649024c6a",
        "department": "Directing",
        "gender": 0,
        "id": 1989658,
        "job": "Director",
        "name": "Albert Langitan",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "credit_id": "5a9af6dec3a3680b2d01f152",
        "department": "Writing",
        "gender": 0,
        "id": 1989658,
        "job": "Screenplay",
        "name": "Albert Langitan",
        "profile_path": null
    }]
},
}
```

Here's the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.moviedb(
id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
jsondata nvarchar(max) NULL,
title nvarchar(200) NULL,
movie_id varchar(255) NULL,
original_language char(2) NULL,
overview nvarchar(1000) NULL,   
popularity float NULL,  
release_date datetime NULL, 
genre nvarchar(100) NULL,
director nvarchar(100)
)
```

Here is an update statement to populate the columns:

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.title = j.title, t.movie_id = j.id, t.original_language = j.original_language, 
t.overview = j.overview, t.popularity = j.popularity, t.release_date = j.release_date, 
t.genre = ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(t.jsondata,'$.genres[0].name'),''),
t.director = JSON_VALUE(t.jsondata,'$.credits.crew[0].name')
FROM tmdb t
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsondata)
WITH(title nvarchar(200), id int, original_language char(2), overview nvarchar(max),
 popularity float, release_date datetime, 
 genres nvarchar(max) as JSON, 
 credits nvarchar(max) as JSON
) AS j
```

My problem is getting the director name.  Since within $.credits, there are cast and crew elements, and within those, potentially many entries each - I'm not clear how to parse through via JSON_QUERY or using CROSS APPLY to basically say, 'find the $.credits.crew.job = "Director", then give me the $.credits.crew.name'.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 where it says *JSON documents may have sub-elements and hierarchical data that cannot be directly mapped into the standard relational columns. In this case, you can flatten JSON hierarchy by joining parent entity with sub-arrays.* - thats the section where it describes how to dig out a subfragment of json, and turn it into another "table" that is joined with the first "table" of json data.

Comment: There isn't a "selection" language for JSON like XML/XPATH so you're not going to approach this like "select only the director nodes" ie. you don't do `'$.credits.crew["job"="director"].name'`- you use the technique in the MSDN article, to turn the entire credits.crew array into another table that is joined to the first data (the first data rows repeat in standard 1:M fashion), then you use a normal WHERE clause like `SELECT name FROM (table cross apply openjson(..)with(colx) apply openjson(colX) WHERE job = 'director'` after the json is "unpacked" to a "normal" sql tabular style resultset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after the comments, I think I've got it now. I use OUTER APPLY for the Director, since I still want to get the movie info even if no Director is specified. This lead me to one other issue - when there was more than 1 Director on the movie. But I think I can deal with that.

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.title = j.title, t.movie_id = j.id, t.original_language = j.original_language, 
t.overview = j.overview, t.popularity = j.popularity, t.release_date = j.release_date, 
t.genre = ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(t.jsondata,'$.genres[0].name'),''),
t.director = k.name
FROM tmdb t
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsondata)
WITH (title nvarchar(200), id int, original_language char(2), 
overview nvarchar(max), popularity float, release_date datetime, 
credits nvarchar(max) as JSON
) AS j
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(j.credits,'$.crew') 
WITH (job nvarchar(50), name nvarchar(100)) AS k
WHERE k.job = 'Director' OR k.job IS NULL
```